# Dice Game made with c#

Tags: c#

So I'm making a dice game for my Assignment and I'm stuck because I don't know how to make 2 of the functions it wants me to include.  Those function are:

For the game to allocate points to the player if out of the 5 dice he rolls 3,4 or 5 of a kind, but if the player rolls 2 of a kind he can re roll the 3 other dice 2 times(i.e. the dice which where not the 2 of a kind) so if the first time he rolls and doe not get 3,4 or 5 of a kind he re rolls for the 2nd time, but if he gets for example 3,4 or 5 of a kind on hist 1st re roll he does not get to re roll, and same for the 2nd re roll but if after the second roll he does not get 3,4 or 5 of a kind he gets 0 points.

And that the game ends once the player or the AI/2nd player gets to a certain value i.e. their score gets to lets say 50.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
class Game
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to Start Game");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.Clear();


            bool gameProg = false;
            while (gameProg == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to roll your 5 Die");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Die.DieGen();
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
            }

           /* if(Score = 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nCongratulation you have won press enter to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }*/
        }

    }
    class Die
    {
        public static void DieGen()
        {
            int i;
            int[] Score = new int[50];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int die1 = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            int die2 = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            int die3 = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            int die4 = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            int die5 = rnd.Next(1, 6 + 1);
            Console.Write("You Rolled {0}", die1);
            Console.Write(" {0}", die2);
            Console.Write(" {0}", die3);
            Console.Write(" {0}", die4);
            Console.Write(" {0}", die5);

            int sum = die1 + die2 + die3 + die4 + die5;

            Console.WriteLine("Your Score {0}", sum);

            Score[sum]=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int tsum = Score.Sum();
            Console.WriteLine("Your Total Score {0}",tsum);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
    class Player
    {
        public static void Score()
        {
            int ScoreSum;


        }
    }
```

Currently, I was testing to see if I can get an array to store the numbers output for the sum of the dice and store them and add them and set a value to it so that once sum reaches 50 game ends and loop terminates, but it did not work (i.e. not what I'm supposed to do for assignment but wanted to see if I can use the score you get from rolling 3,4 or 5 of a kind to work with the array and sum it up and display it).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ Alexis Côté Why will it not go inside the loop?

Comment: Just a thought but would rolling 1 dice 15 times yield the same result as rolling 3 dice 5 times. That way you only ever have to use one function to roll the dice and just call it depending on how many results you need

Comment: BTW - A class is needed when storing some values (fields). In your case `class Die` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, rather than keeping separate variables for each die, you should create a collection to hold your die. (An array would work fine in this case.)

Secondly, the best advice I can give is to break the problem down into bite-sized pieces, represented by individual functions. For example, you should have a function to help you determine whether a 3, 4, or 5 of a kind is rolled. That way, your logic can read like your requirements description.

```
int[] dice = new int[5];
int numberOfTries = 0;
do 
{
    RollDice(dice);
    ...
    numberOfTries++;
}
while(numberOfTries < 3 && !DiceHaveOfAKind(dice, 3))
```

Once you've broken the problem down like this, it's much easier for you to visually reason about the correctness of each individual method and the flow of logic as a whole. Also, if there's a specific part that you're struggling with, you'll get better answers on StackOverflow if you can express it in terms of the expected input and output of one well-defined method, rather than a general "there are some things I don't know how to do on this assignment" style of question.